# How do I help my friends out in the Kenway's Fleet minigame?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag, assassins-creed-4-kenways-fleet

From what I understand, you can give your Uplay friends' fleets a helping hand in the Kenway's Fleet minigame, but how? Can you also do this on the companion app?

Comment: I've wondered this. There is the phrase "Play with friends to complete missions faster" or something like that but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: I'm still curious as to whether or not helping friends is possible via the companion app. I've only ever seen the option to help friends when I'm in the captain's cabin in the actual game, but it's possible that my friends just don't have any ships on missions when I'm on the companion app (usually in the middle of the day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter the Kenways fleet menu inside the Jackdaw there are 3 tabs at the top of the screen, I can't remember the exact names but the left hand side one is your fleet of ships, the middle is available trade routes and the right hand side is ships that are on a mission.

If any of your friends have ships on trade missions there will be blue writing under the right hand side tab that tells you how many friends you can help. When you go to this tab you have to scroll to the bottom of the list, past all of your own ships in transit, to find your friend's ships.

You are given the option to shorten the time the journey takes or to escort your friends ship by sending one of your own ships for the remaining time, this increases the odds of success for that mission.

This option is available for anyone on your friends list, not just uplay friends.

Answer (score -1):

According to [blog.ubi.com](http://blog.ubi.com/assassins-creed-iv-black-flag-kenways-fleet-faq/)

**How can I help my friends?**

```
You can find your friends through the metagame menu and you’ll 
receive the option to either escort them or help speed 
up their journey. They can do the same for you in return.
```

Although I never tried that myself, since none of my friends plays it on ps3 =)

Comment: "Although I never tried that myself, since none of my friends plays it on PS3."... what did you just say..?